# How to add multiple strings of data to an array of the same type to local storage on separate events

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, node.js, local-storage

I am working on a shopping cart application built in NodeJs, ExpressJS, Ajax, and Mongo/Mongoose DB. When a user clicks the add to cart button for a specific item I am getting the specific product Id for that product from the button. I am then sending an Ajax request to the server to get all of the information on that product and sending it back to the front end to be stored in local storage. When the data on all of the information for that product is returned I need to make it a string, add it to an array of other products that have been added to the cart, and store it into the local storage. The issue seems to be the getting the retrieved data into an array and storing multiple products in local storage under the same key at different times.

What I am doing is this:

`var anotherCart = (localStorage.getItem('Product')); // getting what is already in local storage
 var cart = []; // creating an empty array
 cart.push(anotherCart); //adding what is already in local storage to the empty array
 var addCart = responseArr[1]; //retrieving json data from the database. This is getting all of the needed product information to add to the local storage
cart.push(addCart); //adding the new product item to the cart array. There now should be what is already in the local storage and the newly added product
localStorage.setItem('Product', JSON.stringify(cart)); //stringifying and adding the cart array to local storage`

This ends up returning something like this after adding a number of products to the cart:

`Array[2]
0
:
"["[\"[\\\"[null,\\\\\\\"{ _id: 583df3eead025434e61a2172,\\\\\\\\n  filePath: '/public/images/df54528a827f99586135956e45f045fe.jpg',\\\\\\\\n  addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',\\\\\\\\n  productName: 'Far Cry',\\\\\\\\n  productPrice: 78.34,\\\\\\\\n  productDescription: 'Its back again. I have never played this game but heard it is pretty good. Wanted to write an extra long description to see if someone really took the time to type such a longer sentence how exactly it would appear on things throughout the application.',\\\\\\\\n  productId: 'rJUg4uiGl' }\\\\\\\"]\\\",\\\"{ _id: 583df3eead025434e61a2172,\\\\n  filePath: '/public/images/df54528a827f99586135956e45f045fe.jpg',\\\\n  addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',\\\\n  productName: 'Far Cry',\\\\n  productPrice: 78.34,\\\\n  productDescription: 'Its back again. I have never played this game but heard it is pretty good. Wanted to write an extra long description to see if someone really took the time to type such a longer sentence how exactly it would appear on things throughout the application.',\\\\n  productId: 'rJUg4uiGl' }\\\"]\",\"{ _id: 583df420ad025434e61a2173,\\n  filePath: '/public/images/e6f5cab3de92a9365807cb8301f781b7.jpg',\\n  addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',\\n  productName: 'Star Wars BattleFront',\\n  productPrice: 3000,\\n  productDescription: 'This games is like, a game, for star wars',\\n  productId: 'BJ_7VOiGg' }\"]","{ _id: 583df3eead025434e61a2172,\n  filePath: '/public/images/df54528a827f99586135956e45f045fe.jpg',\n  addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',\n  productName: 'Far Cry',\n  productPrice: 78.34,\n  productDescription: 'Its back again. I have never played this game but heard it is pretty good. Wanted to write an extra long description to see if someone really took the time to type such a longer sentence how exactly it would appear on things throughout the application.',\n  productId: 'rJUg4uiGl' }"]"
1
:
"{ _id: 583df420ad025434e61a2173,↵  filePath: '/public/images/e6f5cab3de92a9365807cb8301f781b7.jpg',↵  addProductGroupName: 'Xbox One',↵  productName: 'Star Wars BattleFront',↵  productPrice: 3000,↵  productDescription: 'This games is like, a game, for star wars',↵  productId: 'BJ_7VOiGg' }"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]`

So there are two large problems happening here. First, when adding the products to the array it is all getting added to the first object in the array. Second, the first thing returned in the array is null, this is because the first time through there is nothing in the local storage.

So, can anyone give an assistance in how to successfully add these items to an array and store them into local storage? My many attempts have all been failures. Also, can anyone possibly give a better solution to solve the general idea of storing multiple products in local storage at separate times to then be accessed at a short time after they have been added.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Product` is an object (presumably stringified), correct?

I think you're just getting the order mixed up. You don't generally want to make the data a string until you've done what you need to do with it:

i.e.

```
    var products = localStorage.getItem("products") || "[]";// this should be an array
    products = JSON.parse(products);
    var product = {id:1,filePath:"path",etc:"yaddayadda"};// from api
    products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(products));
```

Hope this helps (note that the "[]" is a string - `JSON.parse(value)` expects `value` to be a string)

Comment: I appreciate your reply. It is making sense but doesn't quite want to work. So when you get the return from var products = localStorage.getItem("products"); the variable products should equal an array of whatever is in local storage correct? I basically have copied your code and when I do the products.push the error is saying that products.push is not a function. I can see the return of products is an array so I am not entirely sure why that would not be working.

Comment: Ah, right, the item pulled from localstorage has to be de-serialized. edited for this. see if this gets you where you need to go.

Comment: hmm.. so everything seems like it should be working but i am still getting the same error that products.push is not a function. It seems like it should be working perfectly fine but I am going to keep looking into why that is not considered a function. Also, big thanks for pointing out the "[]" part and the reasoning behind it. I was definitely missing the "" around the []'s and it was not happy about that at first. Still really appreciate the help you are giving.

Comment: ACTUALLY I think that I was getting that error because of data that was currently living in the local storage. I cleared the storage and re-attempted this and definitely appears to be working as expected. Really appreciate your help. Hate when it is little things like this that end up taking hours of time. Thank you for helping figure this out.